# How do I iterate over different links to create a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have been coding a script to scrape the premier league website for players. It will go into each player page from the main page then scrape the information specified from the table but I cannot loop it yet. I understand it probably is super verbose and horrible but I am still learning. I have stored a list of 843 links which I want to iterate through on both /overview and /stats links. How do I go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Code
player_list = pl_links
player = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/13549/Tosin-Adarabioyo'
urlmod1 = player+'/overview'
urlmod2 = player+'/stats'

# Change url to overview page **************************************************************************************************
def df_function():
    url = urlmod1
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    type(soup)

    # Create column names as a list 
    col_items = []
    row_items = []

    # Use dictionary to pass key : value pair
    cols = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "label"})[:6]
    rows = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "info"})[:6]

    for col in cols:
    #    print (col.get_text())
        col_items.append((col.get_text()))
    for row in rows:
    #    print(row.get_text())
        row_items.append((row.get_text()))

    # Clean rows list before appending
    row_items_clean = []

    for elem in row_items:
            row_items_clean.extend(elem.strip().split('\n'))

    df = pd.DataFrame([row_items_clean], columns=col_items)
    df

    # Change url to stat page ******************************************************************************************************
    url = urlmod2
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    type(soup)

    # Clean output
    sep = '\n'
    stripped = text.split(sep, 1)[0]

    # Create column names as a list
    col_stats = []
    row_stats = []

    # Use dictionary to pass key : value pair
    c_stats = soup.find_all('span', {"class" : "stat"})
    r_stats = soup.find_all('span', {"class" : "allStatContainer"})

    for col in c_stats:
    #    print (col.get_text())
        col_stats.append((col.get_text().split(sep, 1)[0]))
    for row in r_stats:
    #    print(row.get_text())
        row_stats.append((row.get_text()))

    # Remove unused table titles
    col_stats
    for elem in list(col_stats):
        if elem == 'Attack' or elem == 'Team Play' or elem == 'Discipline' or elem == 'Defence':
            col_stats.remove(elem)

    # Clean columns list before appending
    col_stats_clean = []

    for i in col_stats:
        j = i.replace('   ', '')
        col_stats_clean.append(j)
    #print(col_stats_clean)

    # Clean rows list before appending
    row_stats_clean = []

    for elem in row_stats:
            row_stats_clean.extend(elem.strip().split('\n'))

    #print(row_stats_clean)

    # Remove unused table titles
    col_stats
    for elem in list(col_stats):
        if elem == 'Attack' or elem == 'Team Play' or elem == 'Discipline' or elem == 'Defence':
            col_stats.remove(elem)

    # Clean columns list before appending
    col_stats_clean = []

    for i in col_stats:
        j = i.replace('   ', '')
        col_stats_clean.append(j)
    #print(col_stats_clean)

    # Clean rows list before appending
    row_stats_clean = []

    for elem in row_stats:
            row_stats_clean.extend(elem.strip().split('\n'))

    #print(row_stats_clean)

    # Creating dataframe for stats *************************************************************************************************
    stats_df = pd.DataFrame([row_stats_clean], columns=col_stats_clean)
    #stats_df

    join_1 = df.join(stats_df, how='right')

    # Create names as a list
    row_names = []

    # Use dictionary to pass key : value pair
    r_names = soup.find_all('div', {"class" : "name t-colour"})

    for row in r_names:
        row_names.append((row.get_text()))
    #print(row.get_text())

    # Create dataframe for names
    names_df = pd.DataFrame([row_names])
    names_df.columns = ['Name']

    pl_player_stats = names_df.join(join_1, how='right')

    # Result
    return pl_player_stats
```

The function should return a DataFrame except with every player included:

|  | Name | Club | Position | Nationality | Date of Birth | Height | Weight | Appearances | Goals | Wins | Losses | Clean sheets | Goals Conceded | Tackles | Tackle success % | Last man tackles | Blocked shots | Interceptions | Clearances | Headed Clearance | Clearances off line | Recoveries | Duels won | Duels lost | Successful 50/50s | Aerial battles won | Aerial battles lost | Own goals | Errors leading to goal | Assists | Passes | Passes per match | Big Chances Created | Crosses | Cross accuracy % | Through balls | Accurate long balls | Yellow cards | Red cards | Fouls | Offsides | Goals | Headed goals | Goals with right foot | Goals with left foot | Hit woodwork |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tosin Adarabioyo | Fulham | Defender | England | 24/09/1997 (23) | 196cm | 80kg | 26 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 9 | 27 | 29 | 62% | 0 | 1 | 35 | 154 | 78 | 0 | 115 | 110 | 64 | 10 | 68 | 31 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1,466 | 56.38 | 0 | 2 | 2% | 0 | 99 | 1 | 0 | 13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to extract the data from the two URLs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.premierleague.com/players/13549/player"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + "/overview").content, "html.parser")
data = {}

data["name"] = soup.select_one(".playerDetails .name").text
data["club"] = soup.select_one(".playerbadgeContainer .visuallyHidden").text
data["pos"] = soup.select_one('.label:contains("Position") + .info').text
data["dob"] = soup.select_one(
    '.label:contains("Date of Birth") + .info'
).text.strip()
data["height"] = soup.select_one(
    '.label:contains("Height") + .info'
).text.strip()

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + "/stats").content, "html.parser")

for s in soup.select(".topStat"):
    v = s.text.split()
    if len(v) == 2:
        data[v[0]] = v[1]

for s in soup.select(".normalStat"):
    v = list(map(str.strip, s.text.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))
    if len(v) == 2:
        data[v[0]] = v[1]

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               name    club       pos              dob height Appearances Goals Wins Losses Clean sheets Goals Conceded Tackles Tackle success % Last man tackles Blocked shots Interceptions Clearances Headed Clearance Clearances off line Recoveries Duels won Duels lost Successful 50/50s Aerial battles won Aerial battles lost Own goals Errors leading to goal Assists Passes Passes per match Big Chances Created Crosses Cross accuracy % Through balls Accurate long balls Yellow cards Red cards Fouls Offsides Headed goals Goals with right foot Goals with left foot Hit woodwork
0  Tosin Adarabioyo  Fulham  Defender  24/09/1997 (23)  196cm          26     0    5     10            9             27      29              62%                0             1            35        154               78                   0        115       110         64                10                 68                  31         1                      0       0  1,466            56.38                   0       2               2%             0                  99            1         0    13        1            0                     0                    0            0
```

---

EDIT:

To get data for more players:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_data(player_num):
    url = "https://www.premierleague.com/players/{}/player".format(player_num)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + "/overview").content, "html.parser")
    data = {}

    data["name"] = soup.select_one(".playerDetails .name").text
    tmp = soup.select_one(".playerbadgeContainer .visuallyHidden")
    if tmp:
        data["club"] = tmp.text
    data["pos"] = soup.select_one('.label:contains("Position") + .info').text
    data["dob"] = soup.select_one(
        '.label:contains("Date of Birth") + .info'
    ).text.strip()
    data["height"] = soup.select_one(
        '.label:contains("Height") + .info'
    ).text.strip()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + "/stats").content, "html.parser")

    for s in soup.select(".topStat"):
        v = s.text.split()
        if len(v) == 2:
            data[v[0]] = v[1]

    for s in soup.select(".normalStat"):
        v = list(map(str.strip, s.text.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))
        if len(v) == 2:
            data[v[0]] = v[1]

    return data


player_nums = ["13286", "10905", "13549", "14674"]

list_of_data = []
for num in player_nums:
    print(num)
    list_of_data.append(get_data(num))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               name         club         pos              dob height Appearances Goals Wins Losses Goals per match Headed goals Goals with right foot Goals with left foot Penalties scored Freekicks scored Shots Shots on target Shooting accuracy % Hit woodwork Big chances missed Assists Passes Passes per match Big Chances Created Crosses Yellow cards Red cards Fouls Offsides Tackles Blocked shots Interceptions Clearances Headed Clearance Clean sheets Goals Conceded Tackle success % Last man tackles Clearances off line Recoveries Duels won Duels lost Successful 50/50s Aerial battles won Aerial battles lost Own goals Errors leading to goal Cross accuracy % Through balls Accurate long balls
0     Tammy Abraham      Chelsea     Forward  02/10/1997 (23)  190cm          87    26   34     33             0.3            3                    20                    1                0                0   163              68                 42%            3                 29       5    919            10.56                   7      32            2         0    55       39      23            31            12         53               43          NaN            NaN              NaN              NaN                 NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN               NaN                NaN                 NaN       NaN                    NaN              NaN           NaN                 NaN
1         Che Adams  Southampton     Forward  13/07/1996 (24)  175cm          58    11   21     26            0.19            0                    10                    1                0                0    81              33                 41%            2                 20       6    748             12.9                  13      16            1         0    40       28      26            24             6         20                9          NaN            NaN              NaN              NaN                 NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN               NaN                NaN                 NaN       NaN                    NaN              NaN           NaN                 NaN
2  Tosin Adarabioyo       Fulham    Defender  24/09/1997 (23)  196cm          26     0    5     10             NaN            0                     0                    0              NaN              NaN   NaN             NaN                 NaN            0                NaN       0  1,466            56.38                   0       2            1         0    13        1      29             1            35        154               78            9             27              62%                0                   0        115       110         64                10                 68                  31         1                      0               2%             0                  99
3   Dennis Adeniran          NaN  Midfielder       02/01/1999  180cm           0     0    0      0               0            0                     0                    0                0                0     0               0                  0%            0                  0       0      0                0                   0       0            0         0     0        0       0             0             0          0                0          NaN            NaN               0%              NaN                 NaN          0         0          0                 0                  0                   0       NaN                      0               0%             0                   0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, that helps clean the code up a bit. However, my question was how do I make a full data frame from all the links? I have created a list with 843 links similar to the one I have up there. I would like to know how to loop each one and append it to the final df. For example: ['https://www.premierleague.com/players/13286/Tammy-Abraham', 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/10905/Che-Adams',
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/13549/Tosin-Adarabioyo',
'https://www.premierleague.com/players/14674/Dennis-Adeniran']

Comment: That worked great but there are quite a few rows with NaN values? Do you know why?

Comment: @Ags911 Because some information is missing on the page.

Comment: There wasn’t anything missing when I scraped the page on the player called Tosin for example. There aren’t any NaN’s when I did my data frame example if you try my code. There must be something going on in the code that causes it to get confused with that many NaN’s?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve had a look at it closer and it seems the columns change depending on the players. Thank you for your help.